# How to connect java socket to remote server socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, p2p

Related questions are not helpful, so posting a new question.

I am able to establish connection between two devices which are on local network.
But I want to connect two computers that are not on a local network. (P2P)

How to make ServerSocket listen to public socket connections?

How to know the public ip address of ServerSocket that we can use with remote Socket to establish connection?
Or how can I get list of IP addresses that i can try?

Comment: Look up how torrent works. Either a known tracker or DHT is needed

Comment: Your server runs on the internet? Or where? Use ip or hostname.

Comment: `How to make ServerSocket listen to public socket connections?` Just let it listen. Dont bind it to addresses. Your Android app is the client.

Comment: I am running server and client on different android devices connected to different networks.

Comment: Something like a network in your home. And a network in my home?

Comment: Yes, peer to peer android app, not limited to local network.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make ServerSocket listen to public socket connections?

If you listen on the wildcard address (0.0.0.0) then the server should be able to accept connections on all of its IP addresses.

- If it has a public IP address, then a client on another network should be able to connect ... unless there is a networking problem or a firewall blocking the connection or something like that.
- If it doesn't have a public IP address, then (typically) only clients on the same (private) network can connect to it ... nless you set up some kind of complicated relay scheme.

---

> How to know the public IP address of ServerSocket that we can use with remote Socket to establish connection?

It depends on your device.  Check the documentation.  For instance, on a typical Android phone you can find the device's IP address in the settings; see 
[How to find IP address of Android smartphone/iPhone/iPad?](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2375/)
.

This assumes that your device has a public IP address.  This may or may not be true.  See [What is the difference between a public and private IP address](https://help.keenetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/213965789-What-is-the-difference-between-a-public-and-private-IP-address-)

> Or how can I get list of IP addresses that I can try?

See above.

But note that a client (typically) cannot find out the public IP address for a server unless the server has published it by (typically) associating it with a DNS address that anyone can look up.